# Powershell to count cells in one column based on filter value

Tags: excel, powershell, colors

My excel spread sheet has 11028 rows, and two columns.

First column has organizational unit, and second column has value.

In Excel, I can filter the first column so that there are about 100 different organizational units. And for each organizational unit, I want to count (1) total number of rows (2) number of rows with value "Unknown".

If I do this manually, it will take forever, hence I am looking for some sort of API in powershell that will allow me to count number of rows in column B based on filter set in column A.

Is this even possible in Powershell?

Comment: You can do that in Excel directly, look at using `COUNTIF()` and probably the remove duplicates function to get a single list of column A entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try using just Excel.**

If you copy your column containing the organisational unit, and use the remove duplicates function on it, you will end up with a column containing the unique entries for organisational units.  Then you just need two simple formulas: [`COUNTIF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) and [`COUNTIFS()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx).

**For each organisational unit:**

**1) total number of rows**

Assuming Column A is your organisational unit (the original) and Column D is your unique entries:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,D1)
```

That's:

```
=COUNTIF(organisational unit range, particular organisational unit)
```

**Example layout, showing formula for counting elements in Column A**

[image: Count of unique entries in column A]

**2) number of rows with value `"Unknown"`**

For this you can use `COUNTIFS()` which takes multiple criteria.

Assuming Column B has your values, some of which are `"Unknown"`.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,D1,$B$1:$B$10,"Unknown")
```

That's:

```
=COUNTIFS(organisational unit range, particular organisational unit, value range, "Unknown")
```

**Example showing multiple criteria matching of `Unknown`**

[image: Count of entries matching "Unknown"]

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = @"
Field1, Field2
a,1
b,2
c,3
a,Unknown
b,5
c,Unknown
a,7
b,8
c,Unknown
c,10
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

'Total Rows'
$data | group field1 -NoElement
'Total Rows with Unknown'
$data | Where {$_.field2 -eq 'unknown'} | group field1 -NoElement
```

#### Prints

```
Total Rows

Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    3 a                        
    3 b                        
    4 c                        

Total Rows with Unknown

Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    1 a                        
    2 c
```

Comment: Great work - might be wise to show that obtaining a file name from the command line.  As I imagine it will be of most use that way.